# React - State is not updating properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `<Select>` component, which is one of the Material-ui components to create drop down menu. What I am trying to do is pass the updated state to `<Select>` component.

I set the value property of the  component to `"value={ this.state.dropDownField }"`.

I also set the onChange property of the `<Select>` component to `"onChange={ this.handleDropdownFieldChange.bind(this) }"`.

So when the menu in the dropdown menu has been selected, the `handleDropdownFieldChange` function will be initiated and update the state to `this.setState({ dropDownField: event.target.value })`.

However, that updated state is not properly passed back to the `<Select>`component.

Could anyone please help me with this?

Here is my code:

```js
class NewsContainer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    dropDownField: ''
  };

  handleDropdownFieldChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ dropDownField: event.target.value });
    console.log("This is inside the handleDropdownFieldChange");
    console.log(this.dropDownField);
  }

  displayDropDowns() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <DialogContent>
            <div>
              <h3>Advanced Search</h3>
            </div>

            <h2>Filter results by</h2>

            <div className="advanced-search-body">
              <div className="advanced-search-drop-down">
                <InputLabel>Select Category</InputLabel>
                <Select
                  value={ this.state.dropDownField }
                  fullWidth
                  onChange={ this.handleDropdownFieldChange.bind(this) }
                >
                  <MenuItem value="Technology">Technology</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="Business">Business</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="Finance">Finance</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="Startups">Startups</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="Investment">Investment</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="Stocks">Stocks</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="Apps">Apps</MenuItem>
                </Select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </DialogContent>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h3>Top Headlines</h3>

          {this.displayDropDowns()}
        
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NewsContainer;
```

Comment: Don't need to bind the `this.handleDropdownFieldChange` function 'cause is an arrow func

Comment: @Carloluis Thank you for your comment. That still doesn't fix my issue. Do you know a solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When using material UI, the onChange callback has a different signature than the Vanilla HTML/React:

```
  handleDropdownFieldChange = (event, index, value) => {
    this.setState({ dropDownField: value });
    console.log("This is inside the handleDropdownFieldChange");
    console.log(this.dropDownField);
  }
```